Measure of the failure of Stone-von Neumann theorem
The Stone-von Neumann theorem says that all pairs $\{U(a), V(b)\}$ of strongly-continuous unitary irreducible representations $U: \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H})$ that satisfy
$$U(a)V(b) = V(b)U(a)\exp(-iab)$$
are unitarily equivalent. Physically, this means that (given the established framework of quantum mechanics) there is no choice.
The Stone-von Neumann theorem does not "extend" to generic quantum systems. For example, a spin chain on a $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice has infinitely many inequivalent unitary irreducible representations of its algebra.
Is there a measure of the failure of Stone-von Neumann theorem? Naively, I can just count up the number of irreducible representations of my system. If it is more than one, then the Stone-von Neumann theorem does not "extend" to the system. However, is there something more specialized or systematic? Are there necessary and sufficient conditions to check for the failure of Stone-von Neumann theorem?

"a spin chain on a ℤ-lattice has infinitely many inequivalent unitary irreducible representations of its algebra." do you have a reference for this statement?

@flippiefanus I belive that  the usual physical picture is that for an infinite spin chain,  each the set of  of states with a  given value of  $\langle S_z\rangle =M$ is  an irreducible and inequavalent   respresentation of the spin algebra because no application of finitely many spin operations can change $M$.

@flippiefanus Sewell's books, for example.
